# Python parse yaml file

Tags: python, yaml, key-value

I have yaml file and I want to get specific set of key-value pairs. How I can do that?

```yaml
DEV:
  A: "A_DEV_config.xml"
  B: "B_DEV_config.xml"
  C: "C_DEV_config.xml"
PROD:
  D: "D_PROD_config.xml"
  E: "E_PROD_config.xml"
  F: "E_PROD_config.xml"
OTHERS:
  G: "G_config.xml"
  H: "H_config.xml"
  K: "K_config.xml"
```

I want to get something like this:

```py
if I check DEV == true:

output list of keys ->  A,B,C,G,H,K

if I check PROD == true:

output list of keys ->  D,E,F,G,H,K
```

As you may have noticed, I need to get `OTHERS` in both cases.

I tried to use code:

```py
stream = open(yml_file, 'r')
data = yaml.safe_load(stream)
print(data.get("DEV").keys())
```

But I don't know how to concatenated it together

Comment: Nowhere in your code you read the OTHERS key.

Comment: @Itération122442 yeah because I don't know how to get DEV + OTHERS together

Comment: You can't, How would `data.get("DEV")` even know that you also want the `OTHERS`, just do `data.get("DEV")` and `data.get("OTHERS")`. What's the point of taking this kind of shortcut?

Comment: I can change structure of yaml file and add top layer like a Profile: [DEV, PROD, OTHERS] if it help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate the keys (DEV or PROD) with the keys from the OTHERS section, you need to define a function to fetch the keys based on the environment and concatenate with OTHERS either way.

Below I have written a function:

```
import yaml

with open(yml_file, 'r') as stream:
    data = yaml.safe_load(stream)

def get_keys(environment):
    env_keys = list(data.get(environment, {}).keys())
    others_keys = list(data.get("OTHERS", {}).keys())
    return env_keys + others_keys

if DEV == True:
    print(get_keys("DEV"))
elif PROD == True:
    print(get_keys("PROD"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, thanks. It works for me

Answer (score 1):

You need an explicit reference to OTHERS for this specific use-case because your lookup is, for example, 'PROD' and you want that included with 'OTHERS'. You could do this:

```
import yaml

def process(filename, key):
    with open(filename) as y:
        data = yaml.safe_load(y)
        return list(data[key]) + list(data['OTHERS'])

for key in 'DEV', 'PROD':
    print(*process('foo.yml', key), sep=',')
```

**Output:**

```
A,B,C,G,H,K
D,E,F,G,H,K
```

Another approach would be to get the items of interest for all keys **except** a specified key - i.e., you could say "I want everything **except** 'DEV'" in which case:

```
import yaml

def process(filename, key):
    with open(filename) as y:
        data = yaml.safe_load(y)
        output = []
        for _key in set(data) - {key}
            output.extend(data[_key])
        return output

for key in 'DEV', 'PROD':
    print(*process('foo.yml', key), sep=',')
```

**Output:**

```
D,E,F,G,H,K
A,B,C,G,H,K
```